# how to arrange rectangle div boxes without gaps

Tags: css

I've these four div tags arranged in 2x2 grid (middle one only for line break)

```
<div class="rectangle"></div>
<div class="rectangle"></div>

<div class=""></div>

<div class="rectangle"></div>
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

Along with this css:

```
.rectangle {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;  /* doesn't work */
  padding: 0px; /* doesn't work */
}
```

JSFiddle result output shows gaps between the rectangles. Is there a way to get rid of the gaps?

http://jsfiddle.net/brMPs/958/

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=inline-block+space+between, https://www.google.com/search?q=inline-block+space+under - what did _you_ research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either float the rectangles left or zero out the font size for the hidden spaces between the DIV tags.  Here, try this adding a container div and using

```
.container {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brMPs/963/

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the spaces is because, well, you have spaces between the elements (a line break and a few tabs counts as a space, just to be clear). Minimized HTML will solve this problem, or one of these tricks:

```
<div class="rectangle"></div><div
class="rectangle">
</div>

<div class=""></div>

<div class="rectangle"></div><div 
class="rectangle">
</div>
```

https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: also jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/brMPs/964/